# how to get value in a variable on datagridview selected row doubleclick event

Tags: variables, datagridview, vb.net-2010, double-click, selectedvalue

I have this datagrid view:

[image]

Now when the first row is double clicked i want its all data to be saved in variables, like the field `name` should come in a variablename `name` aand `First Name` should come in another variaablename `fname` and so on.

I have been trying to get the values using `DataGridView1.CellContentDoubleClick` event, with the property called `SelectedCells` but the intellisense is not providing me any information on how i can get the value of each column in that particular selected row.

Comment: What is the datasource for the datagridview? I only ask because the way I would approach it differs depending on how it is filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer working for me so sharing it here:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentDoubleClick
        frm_dashboard.lbl_pnum_text.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
        frm_dashboard.lbl_pname_text.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value + " " + DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
        frm_dashboard.lbl_paddress_text.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value
        frm_dashboard.Enabled = True
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the data straight from the datagridview you could do the following:

```
Dim fName As String = String.Empty
Dim sName As String = String.Empty

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentDoubleClick
    If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count <> 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0)
        fName = row.Cells("fNameColumnName").Value
        sName = row.Cells("sNameColumnName").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

This wont however work with the multiselect property set to true!